# Ruby on Rails. Highload. Architecture practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, high-load

Please, can you say best books or resources about highload or best architecture practice on Ruby on Rails. And books about best practicies in web architecture design. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a great reference: http://railslab.newrelic.com/scaling-rails

Now available here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuVcDOUVjW2ePvFapFSHBZ71ya2fLHZS5